# Matching multiple records in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a large table of transactions and need to try and match up rows where the transactions may have been made by the same person. The challenge is that there is no unique key to link them together.

There are a series of items in each row that if compared should allow us to group them together.

So for example the table looks something like this:

```
     =====================
     | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
     ---------------------
  1  | A  | B  | C  | D  |
     ---------------------
  2  | B  | C  | D  | A  |
     ---------------------
  3  | A  | B  | C  | D  |
     ---------------------
  4  | C  | D  | A  | B  |
     ---------------------
  5  | A  | B  | C  | D  |
     =====================
```

So we want to be able to group the transactions that were 'probably' made by the same person based on a matching several different columns with other data. None of these other columns is ever going to be completely unique either, so we need to match the records on as many columns as possible to increase the probability that they are associated with the same person.

Group is probably the wrong term as we want a result like:

```
     =====================
     | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
     ---------------------
  1  | A  | B  | C  | D  |
     ---------------------
  2  | A  | B  | C  | D  |
     ---------------------
  3  | A  | B  | C  | D  |
     ---------------------
  4  | B  | C  | D  | A  |
     ---------------------
  5  | C  | D  | A  | B  |
     =====================
```

So in this case it has displayed the results with rows 1, 2 and 5 together as they all share the same information in the columns we are matching on.

We've tried something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM group_test gt1, group_test gt2  
WHERE gt1.a = gt2.a
AND gt1.b = gt2.b
AND gt1.id != gt2.id;
```

but we just end up with duplicate rows. Perhaps this isn't even possible using just SQL - completely ignorant here so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something fundamental, but it seems like you just want  to order the rows?

Comment: Are you sure that `rows 1, 2 and 5 share the same information` ?

Comment: What result are you looking for?  it seems that a group by and count would get you what you want, or perhaps just a sort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just a simple sort...

```
Select C1, C2, C3, C4 
from group_test
order by C1, C2, C3, C4
```

or perhaps a group by and count to tell you how many rows match on the same data...

```
Select count(*), C1, C2, C3, C4 
from group_test
GROUP BY by C1, C2, C3, C4
```

or maybe you just need to complete your join to remove the duplicates...

```
SELECT *
FROM group_test gt1
INNER JOIN group_test gt2  
  on gt1.a = gt2.a
 AND gt1.b = gt2.b
 AND gt1.c = gt2.c
 AND gt1.d = gt2.d
WHERE gt1.id != gt2.id;
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Completely missed the obvious solution!